# Service not running in background after swiping out application

Tags: android

I am using service for sending current location of device to server continuously in background, but service is also getting killed when I swipe out the application on some phones. It's working if I remove restriction of running background services from Phone settings to the app. I will be thankful, If someone provide solution of removing this restriction  programatically.

Comment: try associating your service with a notification

Comment: [read more here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#startForeground(int,%20android.app.Notification))

Answer (score 0):

Every Phone manufacturer has it's own settings for background processing apps. As there are many android device manufacturers it will be difficult to check for every device group. I'm facing the same issue for my app. It will be better if you ask to check is there any setting regarding background services in their device.